# \AtBeginEnvironment does not work for the questions environment in the exam class

Tags: environments, exam, etoolbox

Please see the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% The following does not have any effect on the output
\AtBeginEnvironment{questions}{\setcounter{question}{4}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  % The following works fine
  % \setcounter{question}{4}
\question What is the answer?
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

When only the `\AtBeginEnvironment` command is retained, the question number in the output does not change.

[image]

However, it works fine when the `\setcounter{question}{4}` is explicitly used inside the environment.

[image]

As per the manual of `etoolbox`, the first approach was supposed to work.

> `\AtBeginEnvironment{<environment>}{<code>}` Appends arbitrary
> `<code>` to a hook executed by the `\begin` command at the beginning
> of a given `<environment>`, immediately before `\<environment>`,
> inside the group opened by `\begin`.

Comment: As you quote `mmediately before \<environment>`, that is not the same as inside the `questions` env. It might be doable using the kernel env hooks (haven't checked)

Answer (score 2):

Just add the command

```
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{\setcounter{question}{4}}
```

to your preamble instead of trying to use `\AtBeginEnvironment`

Comment: Thanks. Do you want to add a bit more explanation to make the answer self-contained?

Comment: @Masroor I don't know how AtBeginEnvironment is supposed to work; it was just clear that using \questionshook wou;d do the job.

Comment: Your answer was definitely helpful, but I will want to add a bit before I click Accept. Why the original approach does not work will augment the answer.

Comment: @Masroor On further thought, \AtBeginEnvironment probably had no hope because the actual list of questions is begun by a \list command that doesn't appear until after a lot of other commands that begin the questions environment, and the \list command sets the question counter to zero; any change in the question counter before the \list command is thus cancelled.